# cuando utilizar map, filter, reduce, foreach

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola estoy comenzando en node y me parece muy extraño que en algunos casos me funcione en map, en otros el filter, en oros el foreach, o el reduce, eso depende si se trabaja con promesas, si es async?
Disculpen pero he buscado y no consigo alguna explicación lógica.

Comment: son todas cosas distintas... por supuesto que todos funcionan en cosas distintas, porque no es lo mismo... que entendes que es cada cosa? cuando usas cada cosa? leiste la documentacion de cada cosa?

Comment: Eso no tiene que ver con node, tiene que ver seguramente con los tipos que usas para usarlos, a lo mejor en algún momento en vez de usar un array usaste algo que no era un array pero que puede ser usado como uno, y esto es diferente a un array normal puesto que existe por ejemplo Array.map, Array.forEach, Array.filter y Array.reduce, pero no existen por ejemplo Collection.map, Collection.forEach, Collection.filter y Collection.reduce, (es solo un ejemplo), por ejemplo si tienes un HTMLCollection e intentas usar alguna de esas no vas a poder, puesto que no es un Array, es un HTMLCollection.

Comment: mi ignorancia es grande pero lo poco que sé, se lo debo a ella, el map itera un arreglo y dado un callback retorna un nuevo arreglo, el foreach solo se limita a rrecorrerlo, el reduce lo transforma y el filter recorre igual y retorna un nuevo arreglo segun el callback...pero tengo muchas dudas mas que todo con los return, procesos async y promesas...disculpen estoy recien iniciando...

Comment: Pero un HTMLCollection puede ser accedido por indices como si fuese un array, por eso es necesario hacer una distincion

Comment: @riven gracias mil por tu intervencion, y disuclpa mis preguntas si las consideras muy triviales, pero en la gran mayoria de los casos lo utilizo en arreglo de json..grcaias nuevamente

Comment: No hay problema.. todos somos ignorantes.. A lo que voy es que apunta tu pregunta a un ejemplo en particular.. porque me parece que estas mezclando muchos conceptos y la respuesta seria un manual de js...

Comment: Ningún método del tipo `Array` (`reduce, map, forEach, filter, ...`) es asíncrono, y tampoco esperan por el resultado de una Promesa, o devuelven una Promesa. Entonces, cada vez que necesites realizar por lote algún proceso asíncrono, recuerda esto último. Una de las formas de trabajar con procesos asíncronos por lotes es con [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all). Saludos